ld: library not found for -ld_classic
I am trying to install amuse code from GitHub (https://github.com/amusecode/amuse/issues/1050) and systematically get to the same error :
`Building wheel for amuse-galaxia (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Building wheel for amuse-galaxia (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [94 lines of output]
WARNING setuptools_scm._integration.setuptools pyproject.toml does not contain a tool.setuptools_scm section
WARNING setuptools_scm.pyproject_reading toml section missing 'pyproject.toml does not contain a tool.setuptools_scm section'
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/amuse
creating build/lib/amuse/community
creating build/lib/amuse/community/galaxia
copying src/amuse/community/galaxia/_version.py -> build/lib/amuse/community/galaxia
copying src/amuse/community/galaxia/interface.py -> build/lib/amuse/community/galaxia
copying src/amuse/community/galaxia/init.py -> build/lib/amuse/community/galaxia
running build_codes
building libraries and community codes
build, for logging, see 'build.log'
creating build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-311
creating build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-311/codes
creating build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-311/codes/galaxia
copying src/amuse/community/galaxia/_version.py -> build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-311/codes/galaxia
copying src/amuse/community/galaxia/Makefile -> build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-311/codes/galaxia
copying src/amuse/community/galaxia/interface.py -> build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-311/codes/galaxia
copying src/amuse/community/galaxia/init.py -> build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-311/codes/galaxia
copying src/amuse/community/galaxia/interface.f90 -> build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-311/codes/galaxia
[16:25:41] building galaxia
error in call, tail output:
  amusifier --type=f90 interface.py  BarAndSpiralsInterface -o worker_code.f90
  gfortran -c -g -O2 -fno-common -o interface.o interface.f90
  mpif90 -g -O2 -fno-common -I/private/var/folders/69/q0sxjwg97jg1_jbm84qfy3vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-bypdxfge/overlay/share/amuse/lib/forsockets worker_code.f90 interface.o -o GalaxyModel_worker  -L/private/var/folders/69/q0sxjwg97jg1_jbm84qfy3vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-bypdxfge/overlay/share/amuse/lib/forsockets -lforsockets -llapack -lblas
  ld: library not found for -ld_classic
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make: *** [GalaxyModel_worker] Error 1`

I believe it originate from this 'ld: library not found for -ld_classic'.
I am using a MacBook Pro 2022 M2, from what I found online this error come from a the fact that -ld_classic is interpreted as a library whereas it is a flag ? I don't know I am far from an expert in computer science...
My laptop is updated, as is Xcode.
I found these 2 commands here (https://forum.dlang.org/post/geyertuotsfadpfemhgq@forum.dlang.org) :
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -Wl,-ld_classic" pip install amuse-galaxia
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11 pip install amuse-galaxia

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Try upgrading your MPI installation.
